# Add a link to the chat profile in the "profiles" dropdown

Tags: feature-request, chat, profile-page

Relatively recently, there was a "profiles" dropdown added on per-site profiles with links to their meta and network profiles (excluding here on Meta.SE, not having a meta site):

[image: Screenshot of the section of the profile with the "profiles" dropdown, with the profiles dropdown circled with a red freehand circle]

Now, I sometimes want to visit a user's chat profile from the main site. On a site I moderate, I can go find the link in the mod dashboard for the user, but that's not an option for regular users or on a non-mod site. I can also manually go search chat.SE, or directly visit the /accounts/ page, but that's quite annoying to do every time.

I've been using a [userscript](https://github.com/ArtOfCode-/Userscripts/raw/master/stackexchange/nonmod/chat_links.user.js) written by @ArtOfCode for a while now, and I've found it useful enough that I miss when I don't have access to it, such as on mobile. It'd be much more convenient if this was built into the native interface.

Could the chat profile please be added to this dropdown that lists a user's profiles?

Comment: Which chat profile should be linked? There are three chat servers. A user can have a profile on each one. IMO, (and what I have a userscript do) is provide a link to the user's profile on each of the three chat servers.